# QGIS add new field for each value in exisiting field on a vector layer

Tags: qgis, vector, fields-attributes

I have a vector layer containing around 17000 polygons with a field named 'theme'. Each polygon of the layer has one of 30 unique values (e.g. buildings, roads etc.) assigned to this field. I now want to add a field to each polygon, the field should be named after the field 'theme' and contain the area of the polygon (e.g. a Polygon with the attribute 'buildings' in the field 'theme' gets a new field called 'buildings' containing it's area).
In Model Builder I can use the expression editor for the field name, my thinking was that I could get what I want with the expression: `attribute(  $currentfeature ,'theme')`
which does not add any new fields to the output at all (it does not generate any errors as well though).

Is this possible with Model Builder? Did I even use the correct expression or do I need to write some code to get this done?

The only way I found that works is creating 30 field calculators, one for each unique value and a lot of expression madness to only populate certain fields for certain values, since the Values might differ on a project basis this is really time consuming.

Comment: What's about using the expression ```concat("theme", ' - ', $area)``` to create a new field using the FIeld Calculator? It would be doing the job are you looking for.

Comment: in your example, your final file with have "buildings" field and a "roads", but they'll only be populate in the records where `[theme] == {fieldname}`?

Comment: also, can you use pthon + geopandas? this would be easy in geopandas

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL to generate what you want without any processing

Go to https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/ take the `ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp` and create a virtual layer using the following

```
SELECT "NAME",
CASE
  WHEN "REGION_UN" = 'Asia' THEN St_Area(geometry)
  ELSE NULL
END AS asia,
CASE
  WHEN "REGION_UN" = 'Africa' THEN St_Area(geometry)
  ELSE NULL
END AS africa,
CASE
  WHEN "REGION_UN" = 'Americas' THEN St_Area(geometry)
  ELSE NULL
END AS americas,
CASE
  WHEN "REGION_UN" = 'Oceania' THEN St_Area(geometry)
  ELSE NULL
END AS oceania,
CASE
  WHEN "REGION_UN" = 'Antarctica' THEN St_Area(geometry)
  ELSE NULL
END AS antarctica,
CASE
  WHEN "REGION_UN" = 'Europe' THEN St_Area(geometry)
  ELSE NULL
END AS europe,
CASE
  WHEN "REGION_UN" = 'Seven seas (open ocean)' THEN St_Area(geometry)
  ELSE NULL
END AS seven_seas,
geometry
FROM ne_10m_admin_0_countries
```

This code could be generated as it seems you will need it more than one time  depending of your attributes. You can see below a code to create the virtual layer

```py
vectorLayer = iface.activeLayer()
unique_col = 'REGION_UN'
other_cols = ['NAME']
geometry_col = ['Geometry']
idx = vectorLayer.fields().indexOf(unique_col)
values = vectorLayer.uniqueValues(idx)
table = iface.activeLayer().name()

cols = []
for val in values:
    cols.append("""CASE
      WHEN "{0}" = '{1}' THEN St_Area(geometry)
      ELSE NULL
    END AS {2}""".format(unique_col, val, val.replace(' ','_').replace(')','').replace('(','').lower())
    )

query = """SELECT {0} FROM {1}""".format(', '.join(other_cols + cols + geometry_col), table)
print(query)

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use geopandas and I understand correctly that you want ~30 sparse fields for each value of theme, here's how I would do it:

```py
import numpy
import geopandas

def make_a_bunch_of_sparse_fields(df, catcol):
    new_fields = {
        category: lambda df: numpy.where(
            df[catcol] == category,
            f"{field} - {df['geometrty'].area.round(2)}",
            None
        )
        for category in df[catcol].unique()
    }
    return df.assign(**new_fields)

(
    geopandas.read_file(path_to_shpfile)
      .pipe(make_a_bunch_of_sparse_fields, 'theme')
      .to_file(path_to_shpfile)
)
```